# Tcp Client is not sending second response packet

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, tcplistener, networkstream

I am working on a tracking device and it is working perfectly when it sends the packet and the server acknowledge it but there is a case when the device needs two acknowledgements against one packet.
I am sending both of two but I don't know why the device is not accepting it because after that the device is sending the login packet.

Note: Login packet is the packet which is sent by the device at the beginning of the connection and also when the device does not receive the desired acknowledgement.Can somebody help me in this matter?

Here is the server side code.

```
    public async Task ParseAvlDataAsync(TcpClient client, NetworkStream stream , byte[] array)
        {
            var resp = Utils.GetInformationContent(array);
            if (resp.Item2)
            {
                string imei = Utils.BytesToString(resp.Item1);
                Console.WriteLine("IMEI received: " + imei);
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------");
                var response = Utils.CreateResponse(array);
                await stream.WriteAsync(response, 0, response.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
                Console.WriteLine("Login response sent");
                while (client.Connected)
                {
                    stream = client.GetStream();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                    await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);

                        //it can be Location data, status info, alarm data
                        //if it is location data then response will not be sent to the server
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Get {0} Packet", (PROTOCOL_NUMBER)buffer[3]));
                        if ((PROTOCOL_NUMBER)buffer[3] != PROTOCOL_NUMBER.LOCATION_DATA && (PROTOCOL_NUMBER)buffer[3] != PROTOCOL_NUMBER.STRING_INFO)
                        {
                            if (Utils.IsVaidProtocol((PROTOCOL_NUMBER)buffer[3]))
                            {
                                //send first response for every packet
                                response = Utils.CreateResponse(buffer);
                                if ((PROTOCOL_NUMBER)buffer[3] == PROTOCOL_NUMBER.ALARM_DATA)
                                {
                                    //send second response of alarm packet
                                    Utils.SendAlarmSecondResponse(client, buffer);
                                }
                                await stream.WriteAsync(response, 0, response.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
                                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} response sent.", (PROTOCOL_NUMBER)buffer[3]));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                client.Close();
                                client.Dispose();
                                Console.WriteLine("Invalid packet recieved : " + buffer[3]);
                                Console.WriteLine(Utils.BytesToString(buffer));
                            }
                        }

                        if (Utils.IsVaidProtocol((PROTOCOL_NUMBER)buffer[3]) && (PROTOCOL_NUMBER)buffer[3] != PROTOCOL_NUMBER.LOGIN_MESSAGE)
                        {
                            Parser.Parse((PROTOCOL_NUMBER)buffer[3], imei, stream, buffer);
                        }
                        else if ((PROTOCOL_NUMBER)buffer[3] != PROTOCOL_NUMBER.LOGIN_MESSAGE)
                        {
                            client.Close();
                            client.Dispose();
                            Console.WriteLine("Invalid protocol : " + (PROTOCOL_NUMBER)buffer[3]);
                        }
                }
            }

        }

   public async static void SendAlarmSecondResponse(TcpClient client , byte[] buffer)
        {
            try
            {
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                UInt16 sendCRC = 0;
                int messageLength = buffer[2];
                //skip start bytes, message length.  then go back 4 bytes (CRC and serial number)
                byte[] serialNumber = buffer.Skip(2 + 1 + messageLength - 4).Take(2).ToArray();

                int alarmDataAddressPacketLen = alarmDataAddressResponse.Length - 5;
                alarmDataAddressResponse[2] = (byte)(alarmDataAddressPacketLen & 0xFF);

                serialNumber.CopyTo(alarmDataAddressResponse, alarmDataAddressPacketLen - 1);

                sendCRC = CRCBytes(alarmDataAddressResponse.Skip(2).Take(alarmDataAddressPacketLen - 1).ToArray());

                alarmDataAddressResponse[alarmDataAddressPacketLen + 1] = (byte)((sendCRC >> 8) & 0xFF);
                alarmDataAddressResponse[alarmDataAddressPacketLen + 2] = (byte)((sendCRC) & 0xFF);
                await stream.WriteAsync(alarmDataAddressResponse, 0, alarmDataAddressResponse.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: All code that ignores the return value of `ReadAsync` or `WriteAsync` has a bug. All code that uses `TcpClient.Connected` probably has a bug. The first thing to do is rewrite the code with the understanding that `ReadAsync` and `WriteAsync` may only partially complete.

Answer (score 0):

TCP is not message-oriented, it's stream-oriented.

You are likely reading more than one of your application-level "packets" into `buffer`, and you only parse the first, then throw the rest of the `buffer` away.

The inverse can also happen; there's no guarantee that you read a full application-level packet with a single read call.

Comment: it's not about reading the packet but it's about sending an acknowledgment.
I have checked by making my own client which acts as a device and by that client, I am receiving the full packet.